# :hover but :not on a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I apply a hover effect on an `a` element, but not to an `a` element with the class `active`?

```
a:hover(not: .active)
```

Seems something is missing.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

The functional notation is on `:not()`, not `:hover`:

```
a:not(.active):hover
```

If you prefer to put `:hover` first, that's fine:

```
a:hover:not(.active)
```

It doesn't matter which pseudo-class comes first or last; either way, the selector works the same. It just happens to be my personal convention to put `:hover` last as I tend to place user-interaction pseudo-classes behind structural pseudo-classes.

Comment: Be careful if you need to support IE before version 9 though as they appear to not support `not()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#pseudoclasses.  Perhaps see the answer by @Mendhak if you do.

Answer (score 12):

You have the option of using the [`not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) selector.

```
a:not(.active):hover { ... }
```

However, this may not work in all browsers, as not all browsers implement CSS3 features.

If you are targeting a large audience and want to support older browsers, the best way would be to define a style for the `.active:hover` and undo whatever you're doing in `a:hover`.

Answer (score 10):

**We can use** `:not()` **operator on hover like below example.**

> We can use this when we don't want to apply `:hover` effect to the selected `item`

```css
.block-wraper {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: #0095ff;
}

.block:not(.active):hover {
  background: #b6e1ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-wraper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block active"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```